# php image upload setting png, gifs to black

Tags: php, image-upload

I have an image upload script that works great but of course there's a wee problem...
for some reason(im sure its a imagecreatetruecolor thing ) when i upload pngs and gifs i just get a black picture...

here's the function

```
function ak_img_resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
$scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
       $w = $h * $scale_ratio;
} else {
       $h = $w / $scale_ratio;
}
$img = "";
$ext = strtolower($ext);
if ($ext == "gif"){ 
  $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
} else if($ext =="png"){ 
  $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
} else { 
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
}
$tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 80);
}
function ak_img_thumb($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
$src_x = ($w_orig / 2) - ($w / 2);
$src_y = ($h_orig / 2) - ($h / 2);
$ext = strtolower($ext);
$img = "";
if ($ext == "gif"){ 
$img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
} else if($ext =="png"){ 
$img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
} else { 
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
}
$tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $w, $h, $w, $h);
if ($ext == "gif"){ 
    imagegif($tci, $newcopy);
} else if($ext =="png"){ 
    imagepng($tci, $newcopy);
} else { 
    imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 80);
}
}
```

any help would be great

Cheers

Comment: If I had to handle such a stuff as image resizing in PHP then I would be more of using some utilities provided by PHP like `SimpleImage`.

Comment: I've experienced similar problems in the past as well. Despite several [bug reports](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43508), the PHP devs insist that it's not a bug. One solution that I've found to work consistenty, is to re-export your images using a single transparent color, instead of alpha transparency.

Comment: hopefully you're checking for success/failure on the uploads, before doing any of that processing. plus, you're simply assuming success on each stage there. you might want to start checking for boolean false values, which is what the GD functions return on failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code when working with GD:

```
$newImage = "the new image name goes here"; //full path

$dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w,$new_h);

                /* fix PNG transparency issues */                       
                imagefill($dst_img, 0, 0, IMG_COLOR_TRANSPARENT);         
                imagesavealpha($dst_img, true);      
                imagealphablending($dst_img, true);                 
                imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$img,0,0,0,0,$new_w,$new_h,imagesx($img),imagesy($img));


    switch($ext)
                      {
                       case 'png' : $img = imagepng($dst_img,"$newImage",9);
                       break;
                       case 'jpg' : $img = imagejpeg($dst_img,"$newImage",100);
                       break;
                       case 'jpeg' : $img = imagejpeg($dst_img,"$newImage",100);
                       break;
                       case 'gif' : $img = imagegif($dst_img,"$newImage");
                       break;
                      }
     imagedestroy($dst_img);
```

Please note that imagepng uses 3 parameters.

Comment: Hey Frank Big thanks for the help, iv applied your script, i can now see the png but for some reason i can stil see black in places:(...any ideas?

Comment: Hey, you're welcome. do you have an example online so i can take a look at it?

Comment: Hey, some how when I removed imagesavealpha and imagealphablending all is o.k...can upload pngs,gifs any jpeg no problem...happy days!...big big thanks...